# How to get an rmarkdown vignette for R package to escape CRAN warnings on Solaris and OSX

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, cran

I have a couple of R packages on CRAN that have warnings against Solaris (and sometimes OSX) that are related to pandoc not being available for the vignette build.  For example, here are the [`ggseas` results on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_ggseas.html), and the [source code for the vignette](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ellisp/ggseas/master/pkg/vignettes/ggseas.Rmd) - slightly changed from the version submitted to CRAN but not in any relevant way.

A cursory google search suggests that this problem is common.  It's also easy to find a dozen issues on GitHub for individual packages, but I can't find anything that indicates a solution.  Presumably the CRAN maintainers are just letting this one past, but it's not neat if that's the case.  I don't like to tick the box that says "I have resolved any notes and warnings from the last submission" when it isn't true.

Now, some lucky or skilled people have rmarkdown vignettes that don't cause this problem.  For example, the [tidyr vignette](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/tidyr/master/vignettes/tidy-data.Rmd) does [not have any warnings for Solaris and OSX on CRAN](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-patched-solaris-x86/tidyr-00check.html).  But I can't see anything different in the preamble of the tidyr vignette:

```
---
title: "Tidy data"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Tidy data}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

or in the DESCRIPTION file, which contains this line,

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

that is different to my vignette which does spark warnings.  Here is what I have:

```
---
title: "ggseas - seasonal decomposition on the fly"
author: "Peter Ellis"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{ggseas - seasonal decomposition on the fly}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

I also have `knitr` and `rmarkdown` in the "Suggests" of the DESCRIPTION file, which is one solution mentioned on various issues discussions (often followed by "but it doesn't fix it").

What am I missing?  What is the secret to avoiding creating these warnings on CRAN?  It's unfortunately not easy to experiment with this, so it would be great if we could get the definitive answer here for all the people troubled by this.

#### Edit / addition - the full DESCRIPTION files

Hadley Wickham suggested the problem is most likely to be in the `DESCRIPTION` file of the package, rather than the vignette itself.

Here is the DESCRIPTION file of `ggseas`, a package that generates the warning:

```
Package: ggseas
Title: 'stats' for Seasonal Adjustment on the Fly with 'ggplot2'
Version: 0.5.4
Authors@R: c(
   person("Peter", "Ellis", , "peter.ellis2013nz@gmail.com", c("aut", "cre")),
   person("Christophe", "Sax", role = "ctb")
   )
Maintainer: Peter Ellis <peter.ellis2013nz@gmail.com>
Description: Provides 'ggplot2' 'stats' that estimate seasonally adjusted series 
    and rolling summaries such as rolling average on the fly for time series.
Depends:
    R (>= 3.1.2), 
    ggplot2 (>= 2.0.0)
Imports:
    seasonal, 
    rlang,
    stats,
    zoo
License: GPL-3
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
BugReports: https://github.com/ellisp/ggseas/issues
Suggests: testthat,
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Here is the DESCRIPTION file of tidyr, the package that doesn't generate warnings:

```
Package: tidyr
Title: Easily Tidy Data with 'spread()' and 'gather()' Functions
Version: 0.8.1.9000
Authors@R: c(
    person("Hadley", "Wickham", , "hadley@rstudio.com", c("aut", "cre")),
    person("Lionel", "Henry", , "lionel@rstudio.com", "aut"),
    person("RStudio", role = "cph")
    )
Description: An evolution of 'reshape2'. It's designed specifically for data
    tidying (not general reshaping or aggregating) and works well with
    'dplyr' data pipelines.
License: MIT + file LICENSE
URL: http://tidyr.tidyverse.org,
    https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr
BugReports: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues
Depends: 
    R (>= 3.1)
Imports: 
    dplyr (>= 0.7.0),
    glue,
    magrittr,
    purrr,
    Rcpp,
    rlang,
    stringi,
    tibble,
    tidyselect
Suggests: 
    covr,
    gapminder,
    knitr,
    rmarkdown,
    testthat
LinkingTo: 
    Rcpp
VignetteBuilder: knitr
LazyData: true
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
```

### Second edit / addition - reproducible on `rhub`

Here is what I see when using `rhub::check(...)` for the Solaris platform.  There are some clues here as to the problem being something to do with images, which fits with [one suggestion on Twitter](https://twitter.com/yutannihilat_en/status/1006288897817509888) (the `tidyr` vignette does not have images).  As there's no point in my vignette without images (it's a graphics package) this might leave me stumped.

```
✔  checking package vignettes in ‘inst/doc’
─  checking running R code from vignettes ...
      ‘ggseas.Rmd’ using ‘UTF-8’ ... OK
    NONE
W  checking re-building of vignette outputs
   Error in re-building vignettes:
     ...
   Warning in engine$weave(file, quiet = quiet, encoding = enc) :
     Pandoc (>= 1.12.3) and/or pandoc-citeproc not available. Falling back to R Markdown v1.
   Warning in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  :
     unable to open connection to X11 display ''
   Quitting from lines 47-49 (ggseas.Rmd) 
   Error: processing vignette 'ggseas.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
   unable to start device PNG
   Execution halted
```

Comment: First I'd realised rhub's existence; what a great tool.  I'll let you know how I go (so far, have spent 10 minutes waiting for my email validation token, but I'm sure that's a temporary problem).

Comment: @RalfStubner yes, I can reproduce on rhub.  The rhub error message has been added to the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, [sitmo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sitmo) has an Rmd vignette including a ggplot2 image that seems to build fine on CRAN.

Comment: The message says that pandoc is not available.  Perhaps it is on some test machines but not others.  It's not an easy package to build, and its web site doesn't offer a build for Solaris.  When I have a situation like this (i.e. not dealing with some older check messages for valid reasons), I just explain it in the submission message.

Comment: Do you rely on cite proc?

Comment: Were you ever able to overcome this? it looks like other people have this problem, e.g. https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/nLTT/issues/35  but resolution is not clear, even when packages are published on cran.

Comment: I am not sure if there is really a difference with other packages. In my understanding you can only see this warning if there is an error (either because warnings are being converted to errors or because there is another subsequent error), else it just doesn't come through. This is not an answer but maybe an explanation.

Comment: You can set either the whole doc or the offending chunk eval to `eval=rmarkdown::pandoc_available(pandoc_version)` this will check for what version is running on the system and skip if it isn’t at least that.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while and it seems you have not solved the problem yet.

I also have a R markdown vignette on one of my imputeTS package ([vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/gallery_visualizations.html)). It has quite a lot of images created with ggplot2, so I don't think the problem is about having images in general.

I have exactly the same annotations for the .Rmd file

MARKDOWN .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Gallery: Times Series Missing Data Visualizations"
author: "Steffen Moritz"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Gallery: Times Series Missing Data Visualizations}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

However, my DESCRIPTION has a slight difference to yours:

### DESCRIPTION

```
Suggests:
    testthat,  R.rsp, knitr, zoo, timeSeries, tis, xts, tibble, tsibble, rmarkdown
License: GPL-3
VignetteBuilder: R.rsp, knitr, rmarkdown
```

As you can see rmarkdown is also additionally added as VignetteBuilder. Would you midn trying this out. Some Github Issues also suggest this could be related to problems (https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues/1147)